# Bitcoin is not sending to correct address

Tags: electrum

While trying to send bitcoin I keep putting the correct address in the 'pay to' section but it keeps sending the bitcoins to the wrong address. While clicking the preview section on electrum the 'output' says a different address, is this why it isn't sending to the right address?

Comment: Can you give examples? If you don't want to reveal the exact address, blank them out apart from the first few characters (as there are different types of addressrs which have distinct firdt characters).

Comment: 1) Do a malware scan 2) Download the non-scam version of electrum from the [official website](https://electrum.org).

Answer (score 1):

You have a malware version of electrum. Did you update it recently because you were prompted to do so by in app popups? Check your browser history for the download URL. electrum.org or download.electrum.org are the only legit places to get electrum.